# filling half of a cell datepicker with a specific color

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

I am currently working for a booking-agency and I use datepicker for the booking calendar.

when clicking ,is it possible to fill in only the half of a specific cell  with a different color ?such as red for example.

This is an example to show you what I want to do.

i need this to show that booking start from the half of the day.

Thank you for any help.

[image: here i select the first day]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a snippet of CSS that would apply a red marker to the top left of cells with the class `withRedMark`:

```
.withRedMark {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, red 15px, transparent 0, transparent);
}
```

Or for literally half of the cell, change `15px` to `50%` (15px makes a nice little triangle, but re-reading your question I see that 50% would probably be better for you)

The above works in Firefox 31.5…for a more thorough explanation of CSS3 gradients, including cross-browser compatability, take a look at these excellent resources:

- http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient
- https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/